# Extract Euler angles from angular velocity profile

Tags: jacobian, orientation

I Solved inverse velocity (joint velocity) at velocity level problem. So, I have actual orientation of the manipulator. Now I wanted to get the desired orientation from angular velocity that I used to solve inverse kinematics. So I can calculate the orientation error. 
$$ \boldsymbol{V} = \begin{vmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \hline 10 \cos(2 \pi t) \\ 10 \sin(2 \pi t) \\ 5 \cos(2 \pi t) \end{vmatrix} $$ is a velocity profile used to solve joint velocity.
Thanks

Comment: Are the non zero components the angular or the linear part of the velocity twist? Are you using Ray or Axis coordinates for your twists?

Comment: The twist is in axis order. $$ \boldsymbol{V} = \begin{vmatrix} \boldsymbol {v}\\  \hline \boldsymbol{\omega} \end{vmatrix} $$ . This velocity is regarded as the velocity profile of moving plate given to solve inverse rate kinematics.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although this is quite late, I believe this question should get an answer. The solution for this problem is:
If one has no other information but the angular velocity and needs to get the Euler angles, using the relation of quaternion derivative and angular velocity is the best option I found.  Then, the quaternion derivative can be integrated numerically to get the Euler angles. Integration of quaternion derivative perfectly satisfies the property of special orthogonal group S0(3).

Let me know if otherwise.